# javax.jms.TemporaryTopic.delete() block indefinitely if broker is not available

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have configured ActiveMQ broker with failover. Any message which is sent with request mode that encounter timeout we delete temporary topic created to listen reply. Now same time my broker gets unavailable and while delete temporary topic thread gets block indefinitely at javax.jms.TemporaryTopic.delete().
Please help if anyone has experienced to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option here as far as I recall is to configure the failover transport to give up trying to reconnect after a certain number of attempts.  The time between attempts can be configured as well so you can manage it to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently facing this issue. So far this is my analysis conclusions.

To avoid the blocking forever when the broker is not available during Temp topic deletion or sending the messages.

### Suggestion-1:

Use `maxReconnectAttempts=2` Broker URL Parameter like below.

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=120000)?maxReconnectAttempts=2
```

The connection will be killed when it attempts to reconnect the defined times. So you have to recreate the connection after this.

### Suggestion-2:

Use `timeout=2000` Broker URL Parameter like below.

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=120000)?timeout=2000
```

The connection will not expire. We can reuse the same connection and session when the broker becomes available.

It seems **Suggestion-2** will be more useful because we will reuse the same Connection and Session.

I will post if find more effective solution to address this situation. Thanks.